# Snort Rule to detect http, https and email

Tags: snort

I configured the snort rule to detect ping and tcp

```
alert icmp any any -> any any (msg:"ping";sid:10000001;rev:0;)
```

How do I configure the snort rule to detect http, https and email?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Snort rule to detect http:

```
alert tcp any any -> any 80 (content:"HTTP"; msg:"http test"; sid:10000100; rev:005;)
```

Snort rule to detect https:

```
alert tcp any any -> any 443 (content:"HTTPS"; msg:"https test"; sid:10000101; rev:006;)
```